# Bash script: CPU stress test while watching clock speed

Tags: linux, bash, parallel-processing

I am totally new to this forum and also new to bash, so please bear with me :).

I would like to write a bash script to conduct a CPU stress test while observing the clock speed. Therefore, I have done the following:

1.) For the CPU stress test, I have created a script named "bernoulli" with the following code:

```
#!/bin/bash
# argument 1: n

function bernoulli() 
{ 
    if (( $1 < 3 ))
    then
        echo 1
    else
        echo $(( $(bernoulli $(( $1 - 1 ))) + $(bernoulli $(( $1 - 2 ))) ))
    fi
}
bernoulli $1
```

2.) I have figured out that by using the "timeout" command I can kill a task after a specified time. For example,

```
timeout 30s ./bernoulli 35
```

starts a task calculating the 35th bernoulli number and the task is killed after 30 seconds.

3.) I also found out that by typing

```
timeout 30s watch grep \"cpu MHz\" /proc/cpuinfo
```

I can watch the clock speed of my cores (updated every 2 seconds) for 30 seconds (at which point "timeout 30s" kills this task).

**What I want:** I would like to do the above stress test and simultaneously observe the clock speed. In other words, I would somehow run the two commands

```
timeout 30s ./bernoulli 35
timeout 30s watch grep \"cpu MHz\" /proc/cpuinfo
```

"at the same time". I hope I could make it clear what I would like to achieve. Can anyone help with my issue? Thanks a lot for every comment!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about

```
timeout 30s ./bernoulli 35 &
timeout 30s watch grep \"cpu MHz\" /proc/cpuinfo
```

`&` at the end will make command to run at background, so that second `timeout` will be executed almost instantly after the first one.

PS: this is rather poor way to test modern CPU. You will be exercising only single core and most likely only limited part of your CPU (no sse, etc). It is not trivial to write CPU benchmark, so you might want to use one of already available. For example, you can take a look at `sysbench` with something like `sysbench --test=cpu --cpu-max-prime=20000 run`.

Comment: Wow, thank you very much for the very fast solution and also for your additional tip - I will have a look at sysbench  now.

Answer (score 1):

You can run them in a dedicated shell:

```
timeout 30s bash -c './bernoulli 35 & watch grep \"cpu MHz\" /proc/cpuinfo'
```

Note that the single `&` is not a typo. It is not a logical *and*, it runs the `bernoulli` script in background.

Comment: Thank you very much for the very fast response! Works perfectly!